# Update query taking long time in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which holds more then 2 million records, I am trying to update a table using following query

```
UPDATE toc T
SET RANK =
        65535
      - (SELECT COUNT (*)
           FROM toc T2
          WHERE     S_KEY LIKE '00010001%'
                AND A_ID IS NOT NULL
                AND T2.TARGET = T.TARGET
                AND T2.RANK > T.RANK)
WHERE S_KEY LIKE '00010001%' AND A_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Usually this query tooks 5 mins to update 50000 rows in our staging db which is a exact replica of production db but in our production db it is taking 6 hours to execute...

I tried Oracle advisory to select the correct execution plan but nothing is working...

Plan

```
UPDATE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 329,471                 
    6 UPDATE TT.TOC             
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TT.TOC Cost: 5  Bytes: 4,173,236  Cardinality: 54,911       
            1 INDEX SKIP SCAN INDEX TT.DATASTAT_SORTKEY_IDX Cost: 4  Cardinality: 1     
        5 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 76  Cardinality: 1         
            4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TT.TOC Cost: 5  Bytes: 76  Cardinality: 1   
                3 INDEX SKIP SCAN INDEX TT.DATASTAT_SORTKEY_IDX Cost: 4  Cardinality: 1
```

I can see the following wait events

```
  1,066 db file sequential read 10,267  0   3,993   0   6   39,933,580

  1,066 db file scattered read  413 0   188 0   6   1,876,464
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

here is the current list of indexes

```
 DSTAT_SKEY_IDX         D_STATUS        1
 DSTAT_SKEY_IDX         S_KEY           2
 IDX$$_165A0002         N_LABEL         1
 S_KEY_IDX              S_KEY               1
 XAK1_TOC               N_RELATIONSHIP      1
 XAK2_TOC               TARGET              1
 XAK2_TOC               N_LABEL             2
 XAK2_TOC               D_STATUS            3
 XAK2_TOC               A_ID                4
 XIE1_TOC               N_RELBASE           1
 XIF4_TOC               SOURCE_FILE_ID      1
 XIF5_TOC               A_ID                1
 XPK_TOC                N_ID                1
```

Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a skip scan where you supposedly want to do a range scan.

A range scan is only possible when the index columns are ordered by descending selectivity - in your case it seems that it should be S_KEY - TARGET - RANK

**Update:** rewriting the query in different order wouldn't make any difference. What matters is the sequence of the columns **in the indexes** of that table.

first show us the current index columns for that table:

```
select index_name, column_name, column_position from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'TOC'
```

then you could create a new index, e.g.

```
create index toc_i_s_key_target_rank on toc (s_key, target, rank) compress;
```

Comment: Not sure what should I do...should I rewrite query in different order?

Comment: I just added indexes in the question